# ClassLoader util to test ClassLoader limit in JVM

Tags: java, jvm, limit, classloader

I am banging my head to find a quick solution to create a ClassLoader util to hit the JVM ClassLoader limit.  The limit is in the 17000 range, so either need to create 17000 classes or have some script that can do it.  Basically, we are trying a break test on the server to see the effect of the impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be referring to the size limit of the permanent generation space (i.e., "PermGen").  If so, you can set the size to be much lower to perform your test.  The command-line switch is "-XX:MaxPermSize=64m" (64m is the default; you should try something much lower).